# Docusign distributorPassword or an AppToken for a demo account?

Tags: docusignapi

Can someone tell me how to get the distributorPassword or an AppToken for a demo account?

I am trying to use the Create Account call (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts) in the Docusign REST interface. This call requires a distributorCode and distributorPassword. These don't appear to be the same as the Username, Password, and IntegratorKey used for the other REST calls.

It looks like you can retrieve the distributorCode and distributorPassword using the Get Account Provisioning call (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/provisioning). This call requires an AppToken be supplied in the X-DocuSign-AppToken header. I am using a demo account and haven't been able to find out how to get an AppToken for this account.

The REST call Get Account Info (accounts/:accountId) appears to also return a distributorCode and distributorPassword but when I call it using my accountId I get a distributorCode (DEVCENTER_DEMO_APRIL2013) but not a distributorPassword.

Get Account Info response:

```
{
  "currentPlanId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "planName": "DEVCENTER_DEMO_APRIL2013",
  "planStartDate": "2014-09-05T22:44:35.8230000Z",
  "planEndDate": "2015-09-05T22:44:35.8230000Z",
  "billingPeriodStartDate": "2014-09-05T07:00:00.0000000Z",
  "billingPeriodEndDate": "2014-10-05T07:00:00.0000000Z",
  "billingPeriodEnvelopesSent": "0",
  "billingPeriodEnvelopesAllowed": "unlimited",
  "billingPeriodDaysRemaining": "27",
  "canUpgrade": "false",
  "canCancelRenewal": "false",
  "envelopeSendingBlocked": "false",
  "envelopeUnitPrice": "$0.00",
  "suspensionStatus": "",
  "accountName": "xxxxxx",
  "connectPermission": "full",
  "docuSignLandingUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/products/sign_up/buy_now.php",
  "distributorCode": "DEVCENTER_DEMO_APRIL2013",
  "accountIdGuid": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "currencyCode": "USD",
  "forgottenPasswordQuestionsCount": "1",
  "paymentMethod": "purchase_order",
  "createdDate": "2014-09-05T22:44:35.7270000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DocuSign](http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-Java-READ-ONLY/DistributorCode-and-DistributorPassword/td-p/9175), the `distributorCode` and `distributorPassword` will be issued to the owner of the DocuSign account once you sign up. They are different from your username, password and integrator key.

Then you can add them as extra header in your calls to their REST API using this format:

```
X-DocuSign-Distributor: <DistributorCredentials><DistributorCode>DocuSign</DistributorCode><Password>xxxx</Password></DistributorCredentials>
```

Comment: I saw that in the documentation. I created the demo account I am using so I thought I was the owner, but I cannot find the distributorPassword anywhere in the UI. Do you know where it should be?

Comment: @huston I don't think the demo account comes with one. And yes, the DocuSign admin's response is next to useless :)

Comment: It's poor wording in the documentation- it says "once you sign up" but really it should say "once you go into production".  The distributor password is something that an account manager on DocuSign's side will give you.  First though, you need to pass [certification](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/overview) which allows you to move into production (i.e. allows you to start hitting www.docusign.net instead of demo.docusign.net).  Respond to one of the emails you received after creating your dev account if you want to get in touch with an AM.

Comment: Has anyone asked a DocuSign account manager or someone if it's possible to get an `AppToken` or `DistributorPassword` for demo accounts?

Comment: I asked but didn't get a response. I think @ivan.sim was correct.